# Math differences?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python 3 and am doing some of the Codeeval stuff and I need to generate a list of prime numbers.

So I wrote a function that would check if a number is prime, and I wasn't getting the answer I was looking for so I found a similar function on this site that does work. However, technically (unless I'm not seeing something) they should produce the same output.

The "trouble" area is in the `isPrime` function in the `range`

Both `int(n ** .5 +1)` and `math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))` produce the same value.

So my question is: Why do I end up with a different output between those two ways of getting the square root of a number?

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    elif n < 2 or n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    # for i in range(3,int(n ** .5 + 1),2):
    for i in range(3,math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)),2):
        if n % i == 0: return False
    return True

def generatePrimes(n):
    primes = [2]
    noOfPrimes = 1
    idx = 3
    while noOfPrimes < n:
        if isPrime(idx):
            primes.append(idx)
            noOfPrimes+=1
        idx += 2
    return primes

print((generatePrimes(50)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your claim:

Both `int(n ** .5 + 1)` and `math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))` produce the same value.

#### I disagree:

Let's look at the case when `n == 9`

```
int(n ** 0.5 + 1) == 4
math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) == 3
```

Comment: True, but: ```print(int(1000 ** .5 + 1))
print(math.ceil(math.sqrt(1000)))``` both equal 32

Comment: @Veo: I agree? It also works for 2000 and 3000, but it won't work on `3**2` or `4**2` or `5**2` etc.

Comment: Exact, it cannot work on integer squares, since they already are their own `ceiling`/rounded value. Adding `1` to these numbers would return more than what you want.

Comment: It's not just integer squares. I think it works for anything that isn't prime. 21 also equates to the same value with each of the two. Clearly, it's going to be safer and more accurate using n ** .5 instead.

Comment: @Veo: Until we get to large numbers (and floating point errors start to become the issue), the two equations will return the exact same number for any natural number __except for squares of primes__. So 4, 9, 25, 49, 121 will all return different values for those two equations. Additionally, because `sqrt(21)` is not prime (nor is it an integer), we would expect that it would report the __same value__ for both of those equations.

Comment: @sharth: Yeah I think I misread what Steve K said. Clearly though, it looks like it's better to use int(n ** .5) + 1 instead. Thanks for the answers (and probably patience) :)

Answer (score 2):

The code, as written, produces 9, 49, 121, ... any square of a prime number.  This is because the upper bound of `range()` is *exclusive* and you must add 1 to make it inclusive.

```
for i in range(3, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
#                                        ^^^^
```

You seemed to remember this when using `int(n ** .5 + 1)`, however.  Or is that `+1` in there for a different reason?

Comment: The ```int(n ** 5 + 1)``` was a version I found. Oddly enough, both numbers if n=1000 will produce 32. Adding 1 to the sqrt version will make it 33. Which I would think, would make the results different.

Comment: @Veo: The exact number doesn't matter.  It just has to be in the range sqrt(n) <= x < n.

Comment: I guess I just figured that if both the numbers produced the same result, that it WOULD be in range. However, as @sharth pointed out above. It's not always the same. In fact, I think I've figured out that any number that isn't already prime, will not produce the same value since ceil will round up if it's a float, but remain the same if not (3 == 3) where as n ** .5 + 1 will be 4.